# VS Code: disable linking between open files and explorer

Tags: visual-studio-code

Can I disable the function link with editor in Visual Studio Code?

My project has a lot of files, so the explorer tree is long, but when I open an editor tab, this file will be auto focused on explorer panel. How can I disable that feature?

The same feature in eclipse:

[image: This function in eclipse]

Comment: I still believe the implement of `Link with Editor` on VScode is very ugly. We really need a toggle button on `Explorer` view  to decide whether to toggle it on any time, not just a confiuration.

Comment: That screenshot is from Eclipse :)

Answer (score 167, accepted):

> Can I disable the function link with editor in visual code?

Yep, just add `"explorer.autoReveal": false` to your [VS Code configuration](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/customization/userandworkspace).

Comment: But then, how can we manually "reveal" the current file in the explorer?

Comment: @Janos Hit F1 or Ctrl+P, then type "reveal active file in sidebar"  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Tell me how to do it in the UI. No way I'm going to remember "explorer.autoReveal"

Comment: This answer didn't work for me so I downvoted. I upvoted @Iman Mahmoudinasab answer because it worked for me. Ideally VS Code should have a simple, easy to remember, way to do this without adding an extension.

Comment: Thanks. This is one of those features that seems like a good idea, but is not in practice. I put a lot of work into getting explorer to the right location on a complex project, and then hitting a source tab messes it all up again.

Answer (score 29):

1. CTRL+SHIFT+P , and open User Settings

[image]

2. Type Auto Reveal in the search box
3. Uncheck the auto reveal property as highlighted below

[image]

Comment: This is now a drop down menu with the following options: `true`, `false`, `focusNoScoll`.

Answer (score 18):

**Using VSCode in 2021**

A solution similar as a **Toggle Button** is disabling the **Auto Reveal**, and choosing to **Reveal** when you desire, actually, it's better than a **Toggle Button**

**Step 1:**

Type: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> , and open User Settings
Or go to the menu File -> Preferences -> Settings

[image]

Type Auto Reveal in the search box

[image]

**Step 2:**

Click on file's tab with the right button and choose **Reveal in Side Bar**
And the file will be synchronized in the **Explorer Side Bar**

[image]

[image]

**Adicional Step:**

You can add a **keyboard shortcut** to use the keyboard to synchronize the editor window with file explorer:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Not really what I want and too complicated

Comment: As a Visual Studio user, I disabled the auto reveal and set the shortcut to `Ctrl+S, Ctrl+[`.

Answer (score 6):

I found the combination of setting the `"explorer.autoReveal"` to `false` and installing the [locate this document extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SmarterTomato.locate-this-document) very productive.

[image: locate this document extension vscode]

Answer (score 2):

Interesting new feautre with VSCode 1.74 (Nov. 2022)

[Issue 87956 "Allow to set `explorer.autoReveal` per specific folder "](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/87956)

Example/Use case:

> `node_modules` will constantly expand itself in the Explorer, especially if your defining definitions.
> I typically never want this, I think an exception should be made for showing what file is open if its in `node_modules` to keep the folder collapsed unless I explicitly expand it.
>
> The reason it's a problem is because there are so many files in `node_modules` you have to collapse it to keep developing, as it's completely useless in most cases to have it expanded and it pushes your work files off screen.

It is now implemented in [PR 136905](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/136905) with the new  `explorer.autorevealExclude`

> - Inherits from `files.exclude`
> - Defaults to same values as `search.exclude`: `**/node_modules`, `**/bower_components`, `**/*.code-search`
> - Calls to `refresh`, `selectResource` and calls from `ExplorerView` are all routed to `ExplorerService.select()`, where the reveal check occurs
> - Recursively checks from the file up to the first root child, if any of them match a pattern then the file is not revealed.

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/20613660/141199536-da5da6ce-b94d-4d07-9472-c61ab3fe0638.gif]

This is available today in [VSCode Insiders](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/).

Comment: This works 1.76.2, Thanks~!