# Typescript in visual code and node_modules

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code

I have typescript installed and I am using ***visual code.***

If i try to go to definition for a typescript function located in node_modules, visual studio expands the entire 'node_modules' folder, and I have to close it again.

It is ridiculous.

How can i stop that happening

Comment: which IDE do you use, visual studio or visual studio code?

Comment: Visual code, i edited sorry my mystake

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VS Code: disable linking between open files and explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41052773/vs-code-disable-linking-between-open-files-and-explorer)

Answer (score 6):

In VSCode, if you have two options in vscode 's user settings：

1. set `explorer.autoReveal` to `false`, will disable automatically reveal files when opening them;
2. add `"**/node_modules":true` to `files.exclude`, will hide the `node_modules` folder from explore pane;

Comment: Neither of those settings will stop the node_modules folder from expanding if you have opened a file in it

Comment: if you add `"**/node_modules":true` to `files.exclude`, then you can't see `node_modules` directory in the explorer pane of vscode. if it is still here, try save your settings and reload vscode.